# Equation that approximates the number of factors a whole number has

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

As far as I know, there are certain equations that approximate the distribution of prime numbers based on their size. Are there similar equations that approximate the number of prime factors that a whole number will have, based on it's size or other variables?

Comment: The number of divisors (or of prime factors) jumps around wildly. There are good estimates of the same general character as the prime number theorem for the sum of the divisors (or prime divisors) for all numbers $\le x$.

Comment: A number can never have more than $\left \lfloor \log_2(x) \right \rfloor$ factors. So, a reasonable approximation for factors is$\left \lfloor \log_2(x) - 1 \right \rfloor$. As mentioned though, this completely misses a lot.

Comment: Look at Hardy & Wright *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* 22.10.

Comment: @Kaynex: For *prime factors*, even counting multiplicity, your log bound is good. The number of *factors* can be larger.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Oop, I forgot to put "prime" anywhere in my comment. Yes, the bound only addresses prime factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average number of
prime factors of $n$
is $\ln \ln n$:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html

The maximum number is
$\frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n}$.

See the references
in the above article,
especially Hardy and Wright.